# How to scrape the coordinates of the shaded area in a dynamic map

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

The url is https://www.uber.com/global/en/cities/st-george/
It seems to be a canvas, but I  have no idea how to get the coordinates of that area. I want to use R or python but don't know how to make this happen.

The ultimate goal is to tell whether a city (e.g., Beaver) is in this area or not.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: I may be wrong but it appears that the grey area is not rendered at the client (after receiving the polygon's coordinates as readily processible text data) but transmitted as a bunch of image tiles, depending on zoom (suggesting the need for probably much more laborous image processing on your side).

Comment: Yes, it is. It has a few "canvas" over the map, making the polygon visible and adjustable. I am not sure how they managed to do that...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.